# Ggplot2: geom_text() adds additional, unwanted values to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have a seemingly simple problem that I can't solve: too many values appear on my `plot`. I only want to see the total count (`tot_q` which is `n`) **once**, and the relevant `pc` (percentage for categories where quality is 1). Here is my example code:

```
category <- as.factor(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1))
quality <- as.factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
mydata <- data.frame(category, quality)

mydata2<- mydata %>% group_by(category,quality) %>% mutate(count_q = n()) %>%
  group_by(category) %>% mutate(tot_q=n(),pc=count_q*100/tot_q)

myplot <- ggplot(mydata2, aes(x= category, y = pc)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity', fill="lightblue") +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(pc)), position=position_dodge(0.9), vjust=-0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(tot_q)), nudge_y = 15, col="red")

myplot
```

Question: why do I get the `tot_q` value twice (the red numbers)? Furthermore, how might I hide the lower percentage (e.g. in category 1 I would only want to see 75%)? I imagine it has something to do with my pre-processing of the data but I can't figure out what to do differently.

[image]

Comment: Could you consider responding to the answers suggested either with a comment to say why or if they are useful i.e. they do answer your question by clicking the up arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the subset data (`quality = 1`) for `geom_text()`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
category <- as.factor(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1))
quality <- as.factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
mydata <- data.frame(category, quality)

mydata2<- mydata %>% group_by(category,quality) %>% mutate(count_q = n()) %>%
  group_by(category) %>% mutate(tot_q=n(),pc=count_q*100/tot_q)

myplot <- ggplot(mydata2, aes(x= category, y = pc)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity', fill="lightblue") +
  geom_text(data = filter(mydata2, quality == 1),
    aes(label=round(pc)), position=position_dodge(0.9), vjust=-0.5) +
  geom_text(data = filter(mydata2, quality == 1),
    aes(label=round(tot_q)), nudge_y = 15, col="red")

myplot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after? : `filter(quality == 1)` at the end of your data manipulation.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mydata2<- 
  mydata %>% 
  group_by(category, quality) %>% 
  mutate(count_q = n()) %>%
  group_by(category) %>% 
  mutate(tot_q = n(),
         pc = count_q * 100 / tot_q)%>% 
  filter(quality == 1)

myplot <- 
  ggplot(mydata2, aes(x= category, y = pc)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity', fill="lightblue") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(pc)), position=position_dodge(0.9), vjust = -0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(tot_q)), nudge_y = 15, col = "red")

myplot
```

[image]